# external GUID to satisfy unique constraint in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a MYSQL 8.x table, each row is unique since the PK is auto incremented. A column transactionID is used to store an external transactionID that needs to be coupled with the row/record.

However a new requirement came and we want to create a new row with the same transactionID. I was thinking to add a new column that holds the GUID of the transaction.

Is this good idea? Is this going to be slow? Are there any second thougths regarding uuid as strings? MySQL 8.0 added UUID_TO_BIN and BIN_TO_UUID function that could store UUID as number.

```
CREATE TABLE `testme`.`new_table` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transactionID` INT NOT NULL,
  `maybe_uuid` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));

ALTER TABLE `testme`.`new_table` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `index2` (`transactionID` ASC, `maybe_uuid` ASC) VISIBLE;
;
```

Comment: What's wrong with making `transactionID` UNIQUE and using it?

Answer (score 0):

GUIDs are not great for use as a primary key for many reasons that i will not detail here and it would faster to use you auto_increment key that is already in place.  But if you also need to store the GUID it is perfectly reasonable to just add another column for that.  And you can use the two functions you mentioned.

Comment: Dave, I was not planning to change the ID column. I will still use it. My concern is the uniqueness of the transactionID let's say per request. Since the uniqueness will be coupled with GUID, I don't know the performance issues that might occur here.

Comment: `INDEX(transactionID, ID)` is UNIQUE even without declaring it so.  No need for a GUID, too.